# Keras loss is in negative and accuracy is going down, but predictions are good?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a model in Keras with Tensorflow-gpu backend.
Task is to detect buildings in satellite images.
loss is going down(which is good) but in negative direction and accuracy is going down. But good part is, model's predictions are improving. My concern is that why loss is in negative. Moreover, why model is improving while accuracy is going down??

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D as MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop


# LAYERS
inputs = Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))
# 300

down0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
down0 = BatchNormalization()(down0)
down0 = Activation('relu')(down0)
down0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(down0)
down0 = BatchNormalization()(down0)
down0 = Activation('relu')(down0)
down0_pool = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(down0)
# 150

down1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(down0_pool)
down1 = BatchNormalization()(down1)
down1 = Activation('relu')(down1)
down1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(down1)
down1 = BatchNormalization()(down1)
down1 = Activation('relu')(down1)
down1_pool = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(down1)
# 75

center = Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), padding='same')(down1_pool)
center = BatchNormalization()(center)
center = Activation('relu')(center)  
center = Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), padding='same')(center)
center = BatchNormalization()(center)
center = Activation('relu')(center)
# center

up1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(center)
up1 = concatenate([down1, up1], axis=3)
up1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(up1)
up1 = BatchNormalization()(up1)
up1 = Activation('relu')(up1)
up1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(up1)
up1 = BatchNormalization()(up1)
up1 = Activation('relu')(up1)
up1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(up1)
up1 = BatchNormalization()(up1)
up1 = Activation('relu')(up1)
# 150

up0 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(up1)
up0 = concatenate([down0, up0], axis=3)
up0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(up0)
up0 = BatchNormalization()(up0)
up0 = Activation('relu')(up0)
up0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(up0)
up0 = BatchNormalization()(up0)
up0 = Activation('relu')(up0) 
up0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(up0)
up0 = BatchNormalization()(up0)
up0 = Activation('relu')(up0)
# 300x300x3
classify = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(up0)
# 300x300x1

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=classify)

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=[dice_coeff, 'accuracy'])

history = model.fit(sample_input, sample_target, batch_size=4, epochs=5)



OUTPUT:

Epoch 6/10
500/500 [==============================] - 76s 153ms/step - loss: -293.6920 - 
dice_coeff: 1.8607 - acc: 0.2653
Epoch 7/10
500/500 [==============================] - 75s 150ms/step - loss: -309.2504 - 
dice_coeff: 1.8730 - acc: 0.2618
Epoch 8/10
500/500 [==============================] - 75s 150ms/step - loss: -324.4123 - 
dice_coeff: 1.8810 - acc: 0.2659
Epoch 9/10
136/500 [=======>......................] - ETA: 55s - loss: -329.0757 - dice_coeff: 1.8940 - acc: 0.2757
```

[image: PREDICTED] Predicted

[image: ACTUAL TARGET] Target

Where is the problem? (leave dice_coeff it's custom loss)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output is not normalized for a binary classification. (Data is also probably not normalized).

If you loaded an image, it's probably 0 to 255, or even 0 to 65355.

You should normalize `y_train` (divide by `y_train.max()`) and use a `'sigmoid'` activation function at the end of your model.

Comment: It Worked! Thank you Daniel.

Comment: Recenly, i tried normalizing it with (data - mean) / std. and i got accuracy as acc: 0.0000e+00. Can you tell me, what's wrong here and why it works with divided by ytrain.max() ??

Comment: You can normalize "X", but "Y" must be strictly compatible with your last activation function. A "relu" function stops at zero (and keeps there). If you have negative Y using a relu, you're stuck. We use "sigmoid" (0 to 1) together with Y normalized between 0 and 1.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again :)

Comment: adding activation='sigmoid' and normalization helped in some models but not all of them. Do you know any other possible cause of that?

Comment: @federico, you must be consistent between your data, your model and your activation. Sigmoid expects data from 0 to 1, tanh expects data from -1 to +1, softmax expects data with more than one element and only one element to have value 1 and all others 0. Linear activations can take anything, but non normalized data is almost always a bad thing.